# MySQL SELECT where if condition group

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, where-clause

Hi this is what I want to do:

to_id: 5
to_type: 1

from_id: 3
from_type: 2

I want to SELECT ALL WHERE `to_id` = 5 only if `to_type` = 1 **AND** I want to select * where `from_id` = 3 only if `from_type` = 2.

how can I do this in a single SELECT statement?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is what you want

```
SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE (to_id = 5 AND to_type = 1) OR (from_id = 3 and from_type = 2)
```

That is, get all rows that either matches to_id = 5 and to_type = 1, or matches from_id = 3 and from_type = 2.

Comment: Is `CASE` needed?

Comment: No, `CASE` is not needed.